# How can I remove arrow labels on a PCA biplot in Python and place them outside the figure?

Tags: python, pca, biplot

I am plotting pcaplots and biplots and I would like to remove the labels on the arrow and place them outside the figure. I would appreciate any help with this.

This is what I have tried so far:
cluster.biplot(cscore=pca_scores, loadings=loadings, labels=new_df1.columns.values, var1=round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_[0]*100, 2),
var2=round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_[1]*100, 2))
ax.legend(loc='center left')

and this is what i get:
[image]

but I need something like this where the labels are neatly arranged:

[image]

Comment: Which plotting library are you using? Can you give some context?

Comment: Hi @alec_djinn, I'm using bioinfokit.visuz which is shipped with anaconda

Comment: Have you tried passing the parameter `plotlabels=False`? It is described in the docs.

Comment: Also, in order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question includes a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: plotlabels didn't work